# Images of a node server won't be shown in my app

Tags: android, node.js, web-services

I'm trying  to open the following image in my android app using picasso for imageView, but it is not displaying:

https://www.mesannuairesvideos.com/uploads/file-1491574016406.jpg

However, i can open it from any browser (whether on mobile or on computer).
Am sure of my picasso method cuz it works perfectly with other urls, my problem is that images in that server are displayed on browsers and won't be shown in android applications.

Could anyone try to include this image in an android test application.

Can anyone test it for me please.That would be so helpful

Kowing that images are on a remote server.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing have to do with the part **S** from your protocol (i.e. httpS - the image you are trying to open is behind a secure connection). Picasso has a flaw dealing with secure connections. But you have workarounds. See this: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/500

Comment: @Lina Hammami , can I help you with something more? If no, please check as correct my answer if you think it addressed your matters. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and consideration with someone's else time and efforts in your benefit. God bless you. Be happy: I am sure you can.

Answer (score 0):

Not working for me too!
I using this code:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("https://www.mesannuairesvideos.com/uploads/file-1491574016406.jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.mPhoto);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. So this is how i have done
Node JS Code.

```
_app.get('/services/user/:photo, function(req, res){
    consoles.log('Loading picture -> '+req.params.photo);
    res.sendFile(_path.resolve('./upload/_profile/'+req.params.photo+'.jpg'));
    console.log('./upload/_profile/'+req.params.photo+'.jpg');
});
```

Android code is here

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(viewHolder.icon);
```

Your url does not work try with this url [https://netic-news.net/upload/_article/156.jpg](https://netic-news.net/upload/_article/155.jpg)

I'm waiting for your feedback!